# Why isn't localStorage saving my variables?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My game is an idle one where you click protons, neutrons, and electrons and when you have enough of some, you can build hydrogen and so forth. I kind of got my local variables to work but now I am having issues with the buying stage.

Basically hydrogen costs 1 proton and one electron, when you click on the button, it runs the function `SetHydrogen()`, when it does that, it is supposed to run based off of the variable `HydrogenCost`. I am not sure if any of this is feasible.

```
var protons = Number(localStorage.setItem("ProtonS", Pcount));
var neutrons = Number(localStorage.NeutronS);
var electrons = Number(localStorage.ElectronS);
var hydrogens = Number(localStorage.HydrogenS);

function SaveVariables(){
  if (localStorage.getItem("ProtonS")){
    localStorage.setItem("ProtonS", Pcount);
    protons = Number(localStorage.ProtonS);
  } else {
    localStorage.ProtonS = Number(localStorage.ProtonS);
  }
  if (localStorage.NeutronS){
    localStorage.NeutronS = neutrons;
    neutrons = Number(localStorage.NeutronS);
  } else {
    neutrons = Number(localStorage.NeutronS);
  }
  if (localStorage.ElectronS){
    localStorage.ElectronS = electrons;
    electrons = Number(localStorage.ElectronS);
  } else {
    electrons = Number(localStorage.ElectronS);
  }
  if (localStorage.HydrogenS){
    localStorage.HydrogenS = document.getElementByID("HydrogenTotal").innerHTML;
    hydrogens = Number(localStorage.HydrogenS);
  } else {
    hydrogens = 0;
  }
}

function LoadVariables(){
  buying = 0;
  CanUBuy = false;
  protons = Number(localStorage.ProtonS);
  neutrons = Number(localStorage.NeutronS);
  electrons = Number(localStorage.ElectronS);
  hydrogens = Number(localStorage.HydrogenS);
}

function update(){
    protonTap.onmousedown = function() {protons = protons + 1};
    neutronTap.onmousedown = function() {neutrons = neutrons + 1};
    electronTap.onmousedown = function() {electrons = electrons + 1};

};
function draw(){
    ProtonsTotal.value = protons.toFixed(0);
    NeutronsTotal.value = neutrons.toFixed(0);
    ElectronsTotal.value = electrons.toFixed(0);
    console.log(hydrogens);
    console.log(CanUBuy);
    console.log(Pcount);
};
var mainloop = function() {update(), draw(), SaveVariables()};
var buying = 0;

function SetHydrogen(){
  buying = 1;
  HydrogenCost.buy;
  if (CanUBuy = true){
    HydrogenTotal.value ++;
    buying = 0;
    CanUBuy = false;
  } else {
    buying = 0;
  }
}


function reset(){
  CanUBuy = false;
  protons = 0;
  neutrons = 0;
  electrons = 0;
  hydrogens = 0;
  buying = 0;
}

setInterval(mainloop, 16);

var CanUBuy = false;
var HydrogenCost = new buy(1,0,1);


function buy(ProtonCost, NeutronCost, ElectronCost){
  if (buying = 1){
    this.pCost = ProtonCost;
    this.nCost = NeutronCost;
    this.eCost = ElectronCost;

    if (protons >= ProtonCost && neutrons >= NeutronCost && electrons >= ElectronCost) {
      CanUBuy = true;
      protons = protons - this.pCost;
      neutrons = neutrons - this.nCost;
      electrons = electrons - this.eCost;
    } else{
      CanUBuy = false;
      alert("You don't have enough money");
    }
  } else if (buying = 0) {
    buying = 0;
  }
}

if(!localStorage.getItem('start')){
    localStorage.setItem('start', Date.now());
 }
  var start = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('start'));
  setInterval(function(){
     ffs.value = ~~((Date.now() - start)/1e3);

  }, 1e3);
```

Comment: Could you make a minimal example that demonstrates your problem without the reader needing to understand your game logic.

Answer (score 2):

At first, i think you should rethink your overall structure. You could shorten your code and make it reusable through OOP:

```
function stored(name,startvalue){
  this.name=name;
  this.value=+localStorage.getItem(name) || startvalue || 0;
}
stored.prototype={
    change:function(by){
      this.value+=by;
      localStorage.setItem(this.name,this.value);
    },
    set:function(to){
      this.value=to;
      localStorage.setItem(this.name,this.value);
    },
   valueOf:function(){ return this.value;},
};
```

So you can do:

```
var neutrons=new stored("neutrons");
alert(+neutrons);//0, 5 on reload
neutrons.set(5);
alert(+neutrons);//5
```

Note the + to convert the stored object to its value.

A hydrogen function could look like this:

```
var protons=new stored("protons",10);
var electrons=new stored("electrons",10);
var hydrogens=new stored("hydrogens");
hydrogens.buy=function(){
 if(+protons && +neutrons){
   protons.change(-1);
   neutrons.change(-1);
   this.change(1);
 }else{
   alert("impossible. Sorry :(");
 }
}

hydrogens.buy();//test
```

http://jsbin.com/pozinotida/1/edit?js